# How to get a local formatted date patterned string in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if locale's date format is Month/Day or Day/Month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135482/how-to-determine-if-locales-date-format-is-month-day-or-day-month)

I've struggled some time now and I'm stuck! I either need a local formatted pattern date string in the form "mm-dd-yyyy" or "08-25-2012". How should I do this? Use `dateFormat`? Please help me!

Answer (score 10):

NSDateFormatter has a convenience class method:

```
[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

You can specify NSDateFormatterNoStyle,..ShortStyle,..MediumStyle, or..LongStyle

Answer (score 3):

You can use NSDateFormatter with MM-dd-yyyy and then use NSTimeZone applied to the formatter to adjust for the local time zone.

This:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", date);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", dateString);

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSLog(@"adjusted for timezone: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Outputs:

```
2012-08-26 08:30:53.741 Craplet[2585:707] 2012-08-26 12:30:53 +0000
2012-08-26 08:30:53.742 Craplet[2585:707] 08-26-2012 08:30
2012-08-26 08:30:53.743 Craplet[2585:707] adjusted for timezone: 08-26-2012 08:30
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. How ever, what I really is looking for is to somehow get the LOCAL dateFormat. Preferably in a NSString. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I updated with how to use with local time zone.  I added hh:mm just for demonstration purposes to show it's local.